# Can I get Windows MySQL Community 5.6 binaries built with SSL support?

Tags: mysql, windows, ssl, binaries

I got the Windows Community MySQL 5.6 installation package from Oracle. To my dismay, SSL is disabled. The docs on the Oracle site are opaque.

(1) Is it correct ask if Windows Community MySQL 5.6 binaries exist for downloading and installing?  (2) Or, as some docs suggest, is it possible add the feature to my installation by installing OpenSSL for Windows, then configuring the MySQL server (Windows) to use SSL?  (3) Or none of the above? Please note I am not asking about making a connection using SSH.

> mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';
>
> have_ssl      DISABLED
>
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/configuring-for-ssl.html) states:

> If the value *[of `have_ssl`]* is DISABLED, the server is capable of supporting SSL
>   connections but was not started with the appropriate --ssl-xxx options
>   to enable them to be used; see [Section 6.3.9.3, “Using SSL
>   Connections”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-ssl-connections.html).

Your binary supports SSL, it is just currently disabled.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me to the manual entry; I was able to find it today (but not yesterday even though RTFM was on my mind).